# How to make your screen view slanted in your particular view in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

How to make an particular view in your iPhone game application slanted  i.e. the screen will be 480 X 320 pixels .Can anyone provide me some code for it Or any useful links for the same?

I also wanted to ask question related to the use of camera. Can we make use of camera into our own app i.e. inside the frame of my application?

I want the code for it and how to design the page in the 480 X 320 pixels view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to start the application in Landscape mode I guess.

Add this method in you applicationDidFinishedLaunchin:  method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

and design your views for 480x320 dimension.

For using camera you will need to explore API's available for it in developer documentation.
See this link for [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Comment: I want it in an particular view....not all view the slanted view and i need to design that view how should i carry out this...

Comment: add the above method in viewWillAppear: method of that particular View. support the Landscape Orientation in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method.